# Q: google app engine app.yaml how to handle urls from within main.py?

Tags: python, url-routing, app.yaml

I have a web site up and running with about 100 urls specified in my app.yaml file.  Because app.yaml is limited to 100 urls, I am trying to figure out how to transfer the app.yaml specified routing instructions into main.py.  I want modify (shorten) the app.yaml file to send all requests to main.py and then I want main.py to route the requests as app.yaml currently does.  I have been experimenting with the three files below but can't get a response of "Hello from MainHandler in test1.py" if I request any url other than /test1. Why am I not getting a browser response of "Hello from MainHandler in test1.py" request a url of /xyz?

Test 1:

Request: /test1

Response: Hello from MainHandler in test1.py

Test 2:

Request: /example

Response: Hello from ExampleHandler in main.py

Test3:

Request: /xyz

Response: Hello MainHandler in main.py

Why doesn't Test3 above also result in a response of "Hello from MainHandler in test1.py" and how can I make this happen?

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello MainHandler in main.py<br>')
        import test1
        test1.app

class ExampleHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello from ExampleHandler in main.py<br>')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/example', ExampleHandler),
    (r'.*', MainHandler)],
    debug=True)
```

test1.py:

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello from MainHandler in test1.py')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(r'.*', MainHandler)], debug=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app
```

app.yaml:

```
application: test-for-rr
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

 - url: /test1
   script: test1.app

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The precedence hierarchy goes from app.yaml -> handlers specified in the program.

- When you hit `/test1`, `app.yaml` routes your request to `test1.app` (because it matches the `/test1` route) which routes your request to `test1.MainHandler`.
- When you hit `/test3`, `app.yaml` routes your request to `main.app` (because it matches the `.*` route) which routes your request to `main.MainHandler`.

Comment: For my third test, where I request /xyz, there is no specific match to this url, so it gets matched by the regular expression in app.yaml and gets routed to main.py.  In main.py, it gets routed into the MainHandler.  What I still don't understand, is when I import test1 under the MainHandler and try to run it with the line test1.app, why doesn't it run and send back the message "Hello from MainHandler in test1.py"? I do not get this message back, but would expect to when I execute test1.app from within main.py.

Comment: @carson -- Just referencing the instance of `WSGIApplication` doesn't really _do_ anything since a `WSGIApplication` should be given a request to route and then it should route the request to the proper handler.  In fact, from inside a handler, it's not really clear what the best way to further route a request should be ... Generally speaking, you want to do all of the routing within a `WSGIApplication`.

Comment: One solution is adding the tuple ('/xyz', test1.MainHandler) to the app = webapp2.WSGIApplication line in main.py above; however, this first requires importing test1.  My problem is the 100 url limitation of the app.yaml file. I don't want to have to import 100+ files to main.py to allow handling a random request, so I am now trying to figure out how to first determine the requested url in main.py so I can wrap my import statements in a series of if statements. I would then only import the module needed for the specific request and direct it to the handler in a separate file.

Comment: @carson -- How is that fundamentally better than importing them up-front?  You're still importing them all somewhere within `main.py` ...

Comment: @carson -- Also, FWIW, webapp2 _does_ support lazy importing of handlers:  http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#guide-routing-lazy-handlers

Comment: I think is is better because some pages do not get requested very often.  If I can put some logic in like "if url == /xyz: import module associated with xyz" I do not waste a lot of resources by importing 100+ modules, most of which I do not need. I will just need a lot of if statements.

Comment: @carson -- Normally, importing them all up front really doesn't take much time or resources.  Also, once it has been imported, it's resources aren't freed after that handler runs so if you don't import up-front, you could run into weird resource contention issues after the process has been running for a while depending on the order that the requests come in.  So my opinion is that it's best to do the importing up front -- Since webapp2 does offer a deferred import mechanism, it's clear that you're not the only person who prefers it that way though :-).